# Convert Hex Codepoint to Unicode Character in VB.NET

Tags: .net, unicode, hex

Short & Sweet: How can I take the hex input of 28E02 and convert it to a string of ?

Longer:

In VB.NET, I want to store this Chinese character in a string:

According to this site below, that character's hex code point is 28E02:

http://isthisthingon.org/unicode/index.phtml?page=28&subpage=E&glyph=28E02

I've tried ChrW, but the value is too large for Chrw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. I found this site, which told me that the 28E02 hex code is a 32 bit code.

http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=28E02

All I had to do was this:

```
Dim s1 As String = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(&H28E02)
```